# VBA left function destination range is NOT populated

Tags: vba, excel

The left() function (not Leftsub()) is NOT populating the destination range. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!!!

```
Sub LeftSub()

Dim SourceRange As Range, DestinationRange As Range, i As Integer, LastRow As Integer

Worksheets("JE_data").Activate
Range("J2").Activate


LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

'Define our source range:
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("JE_data").Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(LastRow, 10))

'Define our target range where we will print.
'Note that this is expected to be of same shape as source
Set DestinationRange = Worksheets("JE_data").Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(LastRow, 11))

'Iterate through each source cell and print left 30 characters in target cell
For i = 2 To SourceRange.count

    DestinationRange(i, 11).Value = Left(SourceRange(i, 10).Value, 30)

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the expected result and what actually does the Left() value returns?

Comment: the expected result are 30 characters from LEFT of each string. The source range (Column "J" starting on row 2 (some of cells contain > 30 characters), but there is a limit for uploading (30 characters), so technically impossible to upload more than 30 characters into destination range (Column "K" starting on row 2). Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "there's a limit for uploading (30 char)?  You could try the following:  

1) debug.print SourceRange(i,10).value and see if that is the source you wanted to apply left()
2) debug.print Left(SourceRange(i, 10).Value, 30) and see if it gives you the correct answer.  
Let me know your answer

Comment: Immediate window is EMPTY....

Comment: that's one of the problem, where the source is not correctly defined.  Some other helps posted answer that you might give a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here

```
Left(SourceRange(i, 10).Value, 30)
```

Already you have defined SourceRange as a Range of Cells

```
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("JE_data").Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(LastRow, 10))
```

Again you are pointing using i, 10 gives you

```
.Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(LastRow, 10))(i,10)
```

That points to the cell relative to upper left cell of your selection which means (2+i,10+10)th Cell (as (2,10) is your Upper left cell of selected Range) that doesn't work. Instead you can directly use this command

```
Left(Worksheets("JE_data").Cells(i,10).Value, 30)
```

And for DestinationRange As well

```
Worksheets("JE_data").Cells(i, 11).Value = Left(Worksheets("JE_data").Cells(i,10).Value, 30)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it helps!!! There is only one issue: the very last row is NOT populated with 30 characters. I think it is because of LastRow settings: LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).row. How can I change it, so the very last row would be included as well in the destination column?

Comment: `Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row` This will return last used row number starting from 1st row. It seems like you are using data from 2nd row so simply substract the unneccessary row like this `LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).row - 1`

Comment: Thank you, Jagadish!!! It solved the last piece of my puzzle. Actually it is LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "J").End(xlUp).row + 1.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to find the last cell in a sheet, I use this:

`llof = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).address`

or

`llof = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).row`

the beauty of this command is that it re-sets the spreadsheet pointers so that any un-used space from adding and deleting lines are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Just from quickly looking at it - try replacing

`DestinationRange(i, 11).Value = Left(SourceRange(i, 10).Value, 30)`

with

`DestinationRange(i, 1).Value = Left(SourceRange(i, 1).Value, 30)`